# PHP 'break' operator with non-constant operand is no longer supported

Tags: php

I'm running this code and I got this error.

```
    $no=0;
    out:for($i=0;$i<count($r);$i++){
            foreach ($r as $q){
                if($no++>$noOfQuestion)break out;
           }
    }
```

This is my error

```
'break' operator with non-constant operand is no longer supported
```

I'm running php 5.4.3.

Comment: so? what more do you need to know?

Comment: You are using it wrong. Read the manual: http://php.net/break

Comment: was it working till now? (on nay php < 5.4)

Comment: Ok. I got it now. Sorry didn't check the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `break 2;` instead of `break out;`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the new***** [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) operator.

*** version >= 5.3.0**

Comment: I do not understand why they even added this goto operator. Can't see any advantage in it.

Comment: @str Advantage is not in this type of use (with loops, which can be broken natively by the [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) operator anyway). It's when you need to jump into another part of the code in certain condition(s).

Comment: That's exactly what functions/methods are for. Encapsulation makes it clearer than just jumping around in the code.

Comment: 'GOTO considered harmful' considered harmful - http://blog.codinghorror.com/id-consider-that-harmful-too/

I don't think I've ever used a GOTO in my life, but using them sparingly and judiciously may present cleaner, more readable code. Even Djikstra, who wrote the infamous article didn't want them eliminated.